# Conditional select hide parent()

Tags: jquery, selection, parent

I have this conditional select which works fine. When an item is selected it hides all other parent divs except for the one containing the selected item.

However, when implementing this script, each item is wrapped in another div with the class="grid_4" - this div - even when the content is hidden for non-selected items - gives me problems layout wise.

So, I would like to hide the divs with class="grid_4" when an item is selected. My script is in a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/N4FKg/6/). (Currently, jsfiddle.net doesn't seem to work in Chrome.)

I have tried to change

```
$options.not("#" + $currentSelection).parent().hide();
```

to

```
$options.not("#" + $currentSelection).parent().parent().hide();
```

- but that didn't change anything.

Can anyone give me a hand with this?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI jsFiddle does work in Chrome, you probably just need to clear your cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsFiddle seems to work fine: if what you want is to hide the `grid_4` divs (i.e. set them to `display: none`) what you need is exactly what you proposed: `.parent().parent().hide()`. I tried it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N4FKg/7/) and it works. Of course you have to do the same change in the first select, too.

```
if (!($(this).hasClass($currentSelection))) {
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
}
...
$options.not("#" + $currentSelection).parent().parent().hide();
```

Comment: Incredible. I was so close, yet so far. It works as intended. Thanks a lot. :-)